# Cloudflare bot caching issue

Tags: node.js, caching, github-api, cloudflare, cloudflare-workers

I am using a Cloudflare worker to get data from a GitHub repository and cache it. The worker appears to cache the files and send them to the user, but in some weird order.

#### [GitHub Repo](https://github.com/colossalchicken/rocket/blob/main/index.html)

```
<h1>Rocket</h1>
<img src=rocket.png>
<img src=rocket2.png>
```

#### [Response](https://colossalchicken.adless.games/rocket/)

[image: screenshot]

#### code for caching

***"r"** is the response from GitHub; **"req"** is **event.request***

```
let cache = caches.default;
var cacheData = {body: req.body,method: req.method}
```

To add to cache

```
await cache.put(new Request(req.url,cacheData), await fetch(r.download_url));
```

To get cache (technically on top)

```
var pCache = await cache.match(new Request(req.url,cacheData))
if(!!pCache)return pCache
```

Any ideas for what would cause this?

Comment: Would you elaborate on "in weird order"? your firewall denies me access to https://colossalchicken.adless.games/rocket/ so I can't look at the response to figure out what did you mean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using Cache API you could also allow CF handle caching by passing caching settings via `cf` to `fetch(...)`.

```js
export default {
  fetch(req, env, ctx) {
    const url = new URL(req.url);
    const targetUrl = `https://github.com${url.pathname}${url.search}`;

    return fetch(targetUrl, {
      cf: {
        cacheTtl: 1209600,
        cacheEverything: true
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue was due to multiple requests to a certain file.
Instead of using fetch, I used the cache.